# unsigned long long VS unsigned long long int

Tags: c++, unsigned, unsigned-long-long-int

I want to know the main difference with unsigned long long and unsigned long long int. Can they be used inter-changeably.

For calculations involving huge decimal numbers like 9223372036854775807, which one is preferred?
Thanks.

Comment: They are the same type. The `int` is optional.

Comment: 1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc953fe1.aspx
3. _Type long (or long int) is an integral type_

Comment: If you are dealing with large (or very small) numbers, you might want to investigate the applicability of an arbitrary precision math library.

Comment: just like `long` is no different than `long int`, and `short` is just a shorter name for `short int`

Answer (score 3):

Both of following types are semantically equivalent: minimum 64bit integer without sign and with equal or bigger size than unsigned long int

> unsigned long long
>
> unsigned long long int